# Не работает websocket в фоне с nohup

Tags: php, linux, websocket, ratchet

Я использую библиотеку `ratchet`. При запуске без `nohup websocket` работает без нареканий, при запуске с `nohup command &` выдает

```
nohup:ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'.
```

В консоле браузера пишет

> Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Comment: смотрите ошибки в nohup.out

Comment: Попробуйте запускать так: `command 2>&1 > /dev/null &`.

Comment: в nohup.out пишет "Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1"

Comment: На хостинге PHP Version 5.6.9, а в nohup.out пишет X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.14. Поэтому он не воспринимает символ.

Comment: nohup такая ненадежная штука. попорбуйте systemd или start-stop-daemon